# jQuery UI Selectmenu - Long drop down, scroll in the list on focus

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dropdown

I have a long list of countries that I init as a jquery ui selectmenu.
Everything works fine except that, since the list is very long, I'd like to be able to scroll down the list when the user presses a key on the keyboard.

For instance, If my list is currently showing countries that start with "A", but I press "C", it correctly cycles through the "C" countries, but the list doesn't actually scroll to the items being cycled.

Do you guys have any idea on how to achieve this? Is it supposed to be working by default?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, its actually because I'm controlling a transition on the ".ui-selectmenu-menu" parent, instead of on the list itself ".ui-widget-content"

Was a css problem.